# As we increase the natural number $k$ in $(A-\lambda I)^k$ the dimension of the null space of the same is increased up to the A.M of $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let's say $A$ be a Matrix and $\lambda$  be it's Eigen value and the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ is strictly less than the Algebraic Multiplicity of the same. As we increase the natural number $k$ in $(A-\lambda I)^k$ the dimension of the null space of the same is increased. And we will get a natural number $m$ such that the dimension of the null space of  $(A-\lambda I)^m$ is same as the algebraic multiplicity.

Am I right? If I am right can you please explain me why?

Comment: @gimusi can you answer this question?

Comment: Are you willing to pay for services?

Comment: And by the way, it does not work to ping somebody who has neither commented on or answered the current question.

Comment: Standard theory, see [generalised eigenspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector#Overview_and_definition)

Comment: But in that link "why" is not explained..@MarcvanLeeuwen   My question is why the dimension of the null space of $(A-\lambda I)^r$ increased as $r$ increased.

Comment: Weak increase (some say non-decrease) of the dimension when increasing $r$ is direct from the definition of null space. The generalised eigenspace is by definition the null space for sufficiently large $r$, in other words the value beyond which the dimension no longer increases. It is easy to see that once the dimension stagnates (does not increase) once, it will stagnate forever. Remains the question why the dimension reaches the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue at all; this is basically because (over $\Bbb C$) the whole vector space decomposes as sum of generalised eigenspaces.